# Is it possible to use more than 50 Labels in AWS Ground Truth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, labeling, amazon-ground-truth

Is it possible to use more than 50 labels with AWS Ground Truth?

For example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-bounding-box.html) are 3 labels:

- bird
- plane
- kite

[image]

It shows that only 50 labels can be created. Is it possible to create more than 50 labels via AWS-CLI or any other API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-text-classification-multilabel.html) the maximum is 50.